# Flex 3.4 and FMS 3.5.1 - Problem sending ByteArray on RTMP call

Tags: apache-flex, arrays, fms3

I installed a FMS 3.5 on my machine and created a new application with main.asc like this :

```
    application.onAppStart = function()
{
    /* Allow debugging */
    this.allowDebug = true;
}

//Client is connected
application.onConnect = function( client )
{

    //Accept the connection
    application.acceptConnection( client );

    client.allo = function(o) {
        trace("test : " + o ) ; 
        trace("length : " + o.length ) ; 
        trace("objectEncoding : " + o.objectEncoding ) ; 
        return o ;
    }

}

//Client disconnected
application.onDisconnect = function( client )
{
    //Trace on the FMS Application console
    trace( client+" is disconnected" );
}
```

This code prepare a function I call with my flex application, named "allo" and it returns the same byteArray in response.

The flex code is :

```
var anotherArray:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                anotherArray.objectEncoding = ObjectEncoding.AMF3;
                anotherArray.writeObject(new String("foo"));
                nconn.call(func, echoResponder, anotherArray);
```

As a result, I get an empty ByteArray with only length,encoding, endian and position parameters. And a tcpdump trace shows that the ByteArray is empty.

So I wonder if it's only a pointer which is sent, or maybe I misconfigured something.

Do you know a way to investigate further or solve this ?

Thanks for any help,

---

MP

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code.

Sending...

```
var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();                      
bytes.objectEncoding = ObjectEncoding.AMF3;                 
bytes.writeObject(new String("foo"));                       
nc.call("allo", new Responder(_onResult, _onStatus), bytes);
```

... and receiving...

```
private function _onResult(result:*):void        
{
    var bytes:ByteArray = ByteArray(result);     
    var str:String = String(bytes.readObject()); 
    trace(str);                                  
}
```

traces `foo`

I think your code is OK. Only difference is that I use FMS 4.